# Formatting the acquired data from cells in a table using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the values from a table like the format below:

```
Stephen Curry
Michael Jordan
```

With my code below, I get the cell values but it is in this format:

```
StephenMichael CurryJordan
```

This is my code:

**To get the values**

```
var tableHtml = "<label>Visitors: </label><br/>";
$('#visitorTable').each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var fName = item.find('.FirstName').text();
    var lName = item.find('.LastName').text();
    tableHtml += "<label>" + fName + "</label>&nbsp;" +
        "<label>" + lName + "</label><br/>";
});
```

**My Table**

```
<table class="table" id="visitorTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="true" name="FirstName"  class="FirstName"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true" name="FirstName"  class="LastName"></td>
        <td>
            <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<!-- clonable table line -->
<tr class="hide">
    <td contenteditable="true" name="FirstName"  class="FirstName"></td>
    <td contenteditable="true" name="LastName" class="LastName"></td>
    <td>
        <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Can you please show me how to get this right. Thank you.

Comment: It not all code, please share how you insert in html and also share table, better in some online editor.

Comment: I edited the codes. Please look.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You cannot have same IDs. Rather use `class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must work better, you really find all .FirstName in table, and I suppose it use first or last one, add TR so loop will be for each row in table, in fact each is nothing in your code as it is 1 interation for 1 table.

```
$('#visitorTable tr').each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var fName = item.find('.FirstName').text();
    var lName = item.find('.LastName').text();
    tableHtml += "<label>" + fName + "</label>&nbsp;" +
        "<label>" + lName + "</label><br/>";
});
```

Comment: Yes right, your code just transform array to string, that's why few names unioned.